# How can I edit a value stored at an address through C++?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I need to be able to edit two regions of memory that are pointed to by two addresses stored in the ECX & EAX registers.

I'm doing this by placing a Code Cave in the clients original Executable that jumps to my Prepare_Encrypt() function.

My general idea is that Prepare_Encrypt() would get the addresses and should somehow be able to use them to create a pointer to the data in C++.

Once the pointer has been created I would create a For Loop that would preform an XOR operation on each character value in the pointer.

I'm new to using inline assembly so I would really like to get this working the way I want.

I figured creating a char* and using a MOV operation would work, but it doesn't. Does anyone have any ideas of how to get this to work?

Here is my current Prepare_Encrypt() function and my current Encrypt() function.

```
DWORD_PTR* data1_address = NULL;
DWORD_PTR* data2_address = NULL;

void Encrypt()
{
    // Somehow create a pointer to the memory location at the address stored in data1_address & data2_address. Something like this...
    //char* data1_pointer = CreatePointerFromAddress(data1_address);
    //char* data2_pointer = CreatePointerFromAddress(data2_address);

    for(var i = 0; i < sizeof(data1_pointer); i++)
    {
        data1_pointer[i] ^= 200;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < sizeof(data2_pointer); i++)
    {
        data2_pointer[i] ^= 125;
    }
}

_declspec(naked) void Prepare_Encrypt()
{
    // Save program state.
    __asm
    {
        MOV ECX, ESI
        MOV DWORD PTR SS : [ESP+0x1C], EAX
        PUSHAD
        PUSHFD

        // Get Current Data From Memory
        MOV data1_address, ECX
        MOV data2_address, EAX
    }

    Encrypt();

    // Restore the program state and return to original code.
    __asm
    {
        POPFD
        POPAD
        JMP SendJMPTo
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code overwrites `ECX` with `ESI` and a stack slot with `EAX` ... is that intended?

Comment: Yes that is code that is code that was overridden when I added the code cave, so it needed to be added inside the codecave.

Comment: Do you want to change memory pointed to by `EAX` and `ECX` or do you want to change the pointers themselves? In the former case, `sizeof()` won't work because that gives the size of the pointer, and in the latter case you are of course discarding the decrypted value by restoring the original registers.

Comment: I want to change the memory pointed to by EAX and ECX.

Yes I'm aware that sizeof won't work due to it being given the address and not the contents. That is exactly my problem. I don't know how I would grab the data at that that address and assign it to a pointer.

I've edited my code so that becomes more clear...

Comment: You store the pointers all right, it's just `sizeof` that won't work. The code as-is should be decrypting the first 4 bytes of both memory regions. You need to know the length to decrypt yourself. How does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the size of both arrays if you want to do something on them.

Either use global variables (i.e. `.data` section) or push them as arguments to `Encrpyt()`.

Something along the lines:

```
#include "stdio.h"

void* pdata1 = NULL;
void* pdata2 = NULL;
size_t size_data1 = 0;
size_t size_data2 = 0;

/* test stuff */

void* test1 = NULL;
void* test2 = NULL;

void test(){
    test1 = malloc(0x100);
    memset(test1, 0x41, 0x100);
    test2 = malloc(0x100);
    memset(test2, 0x43, 0x100);
}

/* end test stuff*/

void Encrypt() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size_data1; ++i) {
        ((char*)(pdata1))[i] ^= 0x42;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size_data2; ++i) {
        ((char*)(pdata2))[i] ^= 0x42;
    }
}


_declspec(naked) void Prepare_Encrypt() {
    __asm{
            ; test stuff
            mov ecx, test1
            mov eax, test2
            ; end test

            pushad
            pushfd

            ; set pointers
            mov pdata1, ecx
            mov pdata2, eax

            ; set sizes
            mov size_data1, 100h
            mov size_data2, 100h

    }

    Encrypt();

    __asm {
        popfd
        popad

        ;.... return somewhere
        ret
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    test();

    Prepare_Encrypt();

    return 0;
}
```